# Create user using pyad without password expired

Tags: python, python-2.7, active-directory, ldap, pyad

I'm using this code to create a user in active directory, using the `pyad` module in Python 2.7:

```
from pyad import *
pyad.set_defaults(ldap_server="IT-LHQ-DC1.LIFEALIKE.LAB", username="administrator", password="password")

ou = pyad.adcontainer.ADContainer.from_dn("ou=All_Users, dc=LIFEALIKE, dc=LAB")
new_user = pyad.aduser.ADUser.create("test.02", ou, password="password")
```

How can I create a user with the checkbox of "No Password Expire"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AD, it's set via the `userAccountControl` attribute, which is a bit flag: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772300.aspx

The pyad library actually gives a method to modify this. This is what [the documentation](https://zakird.com/pyad/objects.html) says:

> **set_user_account_control_setting**(userFlag, newValue)
>
> Sets a single setting in UserAccountControl.
>
> UserFlag must be a value from ADS_USER_FLAG dictionary keys. Moreinformation can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772300.aspx. newValue accepts boolean values

I am not a Python programmer, but if I understand this correctly, it would look something like this:

```
new_user.set_user_account_control_setting("DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD", True)
```